# LLVM - Wrapper Pass Class

Tags: compiler-construction, clang, llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

I am trying to create a Wrapper Pass Class for a custom LLVM pass that I have written.

I was mostly trying to derive it from the Dependency Analysis [source code](https://llvm.org/doxygen/DependenceAnalysis_8cpp_source.html). I was able to build the following wrapper class successfully. The code is described below:

```
INITIALIZE_PASS_BEGIN(ArrayDependenceWrapperPass,"dda","try1",false,true)
INITIALIZE_PASS_END(ArrayDependenceWrapperPass,"dda","try1",false,true)

char ArrayDependenceWrapperPass::ID=0;

ArrayDependenceWrapperPass::ArrayDependenceWrapperPass() : FunctionPass(ID) {
   initializeArrayDependenceWrapperPassPass(*PassRegistry::getPassRegistry());
 }

FunctionPass *llvm::createArrayDependenceWrapperPass() {
   return new ArrayDependenceWrapperPass();
}

bool ArrayDependenceWrapperPass::runOnFunction(Function &F) {
     //code for analysis
   return false;
}
```

I have added `initializeArrayDependenceWrapperPassPass(*PassRegistry::getPassRegistry())` to `initializePasses.h` and `(void) llvm::createArrayDependenceWrapperPass()` to `LinkallPasses.h`. Following this when I try to run this with another pass as below:

```
class Driver : public FunctionPass {
   public:
   static char ID;      
   Driver() : FunctionPass(ID) {}   
  
   void getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage &AU) const {
      AU.addRequired<ArrayDependenceWrapperPass>();
    }

   bool runOnFunction(Function &F) override {
    //getAnalysis<ArrayDependenceWrapperPass>();    
      F.dump();
   }
};
char Driver::ID=0;
static RegisterPass<Driver> X("dda", "test");
```

I get a core dump with the following assertion:

```
Assertion `PI && "Expected required passes to be initialized"' failed
```

I am guessing this requires the pass to be initialized which I have already done? Any idea as to what the problem might be?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

That assertion error is in `void PMTopLevelManager::schedulePass(Pass *P)` function, as it can be seen [here in lib/IR/LegacyPassManager.cpp](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/blob/62ec4ac90738a5f2d209ed28c822223e58aaaeb7/llvm/lib/IR/LegacyPassManager.cpp). Are you only getting that assertion error? No more information? Have you tried debugging with `gdb`?

LLVM API has changed a lot over the years, so maybe solutions that work even some months ago are not valid in current versions. Said this, in the mailing list this error [has been reported for other passes here](http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/llvm-dev/2011-December/045949.html) and [here](http://clang-developers.42468.n3.nabble.com/Assertion-PI-amp-amp-quot-Expected-required-passes-to-be-initialized-quot-failed-td4037686.html) as well.

You should consider following steps mentioned in [LLVM's documentation](https://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem which was adding the wrapper pass in PassManagerBuilder in `lib/Transform/IPO/PassManagerBuilder.cpp` under

```
PassManagerBuilder::populateFunctionPassManager(
    legacy::FunctionPassManager &FPM)
```

as

```
FPM.add(createArrayDependenceWrapperPass())
```